# Read text file in Matlab with different row beginning of data

Tags: matlab

```
#- created from binary Format 
#0-Mon, 08 Jan 2018 22:43:37 GMT  
#1-Mon, 08 Jan 2018 22:49:21 GMT  

[data1:100]
0.05488 20.096462
0.10464 20.096462
0.15456 20.032051
0.20432 20.096462
0.25408 20.096462
#--finish--

[adudatal]
0.00686656
0.0121767
0.016571298
0.016388189
0.0039368276
-0.0057679103
#--finish--
```

The data does not begin always at the same row after header text, so the following code doesn't work:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','rt');
A = textscan(fid, '%f', 'HeaderLines',3);
A = A{1};
fclose(fid);
```

or

```
M = dlmread(filename,delimiter,[R1 C1 R2 C2])
```

How to read only the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much faster method is to load the whole file into a string and then use regular expressions to extract what you want before parsing it.

It is not clear to me what data you want to extract. Assuming you wanted to extract two sets of data from the example above where each data set is between [???] and #--finish--

```
Text = fileread('data.txt')
data1 = str2num(regexp(Text, '(?<=\[data1:100\]).*?(?=#--finish--)', 'match', 'once');
adudatal = str2num(regexp(Text, '(?<=\[adudatal\]).*?(?=#--finish--)', 'match', 'once');
```

Regular expressions can seem daunting, and there are many ways to obtain the same result, but they are super powerful. I'll run through the above. The first line simply reads the file into a string. The second two extracts the numbers as a string and then converts it into a numeric array.

The bit *(?<=[some text])* finds matches preceded by *[some text]*. Note that the square brackets need to be *escaped* since they have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Similarly the bit *(?=#--finish--)* finds matches succeeded by *#--finish--*.

The actual match is performed by *.*?* which performs a lazy search for everything. By lazy, this means stop as soon as possible, which means the first time *#--finish--* is found.

The additional arguments 'match' and 'once' in regexp mean return the match found and only do so once. This is returned as a character array, which can be converted into a numeric array using str2num. Try it without str2num to see what the regular expression does.

You could be even cleverer and extract the variable name, but it can get quite complex and messy. You could break the problem down into two steps: (1) find variables between square brackets and (2) loop through found variables in a for loop (converting the variable string into a valid matlab identifier).

Comment: Indeed much faster method. My data of interest are after [adudatal]. I tested how fast your method is, the elapsed time is 0.030550 seconds while using IO function the elapsed time is 0.056982 seconds.For files with a large number of samples using your approach, performance is much much better.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the file structure is kinda difficult to parse using conventional IO functions. Since they can't serve your purpose, a manual approach may be required, which involves reading the file line by line and parsing it once the proper offset is reached:

```
adudatal = [];
reading = false;

fid = fopen('data.txt','r');

while (~feof(fid))
    line = fgets(fid);

    if (strcmp(strtrim(line),'[adudatal]'))
        reading = true;
        continue;
    end

    if (~reading)
        continue;
    end

    if (strcmp(strtrim(line),'#--finish--'))
        break;
    end

    adudatal(end+1) = sscanf(line,'%f');
end

fclose(fid);
```

Output:

```
adudatal = 
    [0.006866560000000 0.012176700000000 0.016571298000000 0.016388189000000 0.003936827600000 -0.005767910300000]
```

Comment: Your approach Mommaso works. I forgot to include the "#--finish--" line in the file after data and I receive an error "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.". I also update the content of question to reflect it. I wish I can solve to have the completely fully functional script?